# __set and Property Overloading

Tags: php

```
class object
{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function __set($property, $value) 
    { 
         $this->$property = $value;
    }

    public function __get($property) 
    {
        if (isset($property))
            return $this->$property;
    }
}
```

I get the concept of Property Overloading now. But I'm not entirely sure why the code have double $'s.

For example this statement: `$this->$property = $value;` versus the usual `$this->property = $value;`

My guess is that the reason why both statement are different is:

The `$this->property = $value` statement is use when the class have explicitly defined property. To clarified, code with a property that is explicitly defined:
`class object { private $property; __construct(){} /... setter, getter/ }`

Where as `$this->$property = $value;` is used for dynamically created property. So `$this->$property` is actually referring to the `_set`'s $property argument. For clarity: `_set($property,$value)`, the first `__set` method's argument (bolded).

Heck, maybe the code is just creating a new variable named `$property`, instead of referring to the 1st argument in the `__set`, and `$this->` is just forcing the class to acknowledge that the class have a new property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is right. This is one use of variable variables; in this specific case, variable class properties.

PHP parses `$this->$property` as `$this->{string value of $property}`, and returns the property of your object that named whatever `$property` is set to.

Your `__get()` implementation is slightly off though, you forgot `$this->`:

```
        if (isset($this->$property))
            return $this->$property;
```

Comment: __get won't be called if the given property exists as an accessible member of that object: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

So the code example will never be run, assuming it is within the __get method itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [variable variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
public function __set($property, $value) 
{ 
     $this->$property = $value;
}
```

So when you do `$this->foo = 'bar'` PHP will notice the there is no accessible property foo available and delegate to the `__set` method with 'foo' for `$property` and 'bar' for `$value`. This, in turn, is evaluated to the following expression:

```
$this->foo = 'bar';
```

On a sidenote, `__get` and `__set` are not a replacement for proper getters and setters. They are much more related to error handling. They are also much slower than using regular functions and they also make your API harder to read.

Comment: "__get and __set are not a replacement for proper getters and setters. They are much more related to error handling." Do you have a link or reference to this? I would like to read more on this. I've google it up and only found that magic functions are slow. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @myth I dont have an article for that. But it's obvious, isn't it? Trying to read or set an inaccessible property will raise an error. Putting __get/__set in place gives you a chance to handle that error with custom logic. A proper getter or setter doesnt have that overhead and they are also much clearer to new developers who try to understand how they can interact with your class. With a magic method, I will have to look at the code to understand what it does. I cannot see that from the API. And note __get/__set do not behave the same as direct assignments (as noted in the Manual for __get).

Answer (score 1):

If `$property="myVar"` , by using `$this->$property` you are actually refering to `$this->myVar` .. it's kinda like `$var1='test'; $test=10; echo $$var1;` returns 10 :)